# Angular 2 : Http POST errors

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a POST sign up service in angular2 but it doesn't work that well.
So here's my **user.ts** :

```
export class User {
    id:number;
    name:string;
    email:string;
    birthDate:Date;
}
```

Then **signup.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { User } from "../../models/user";

@Injectable()
export class SignupService {
  url: string = 'http://localhost:8080/signup';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  createUser(user: User): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http
      .post(this.url, user, options)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
  }
  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || {};
  }
  private handleErrorObservable(error: Response | any) {
    console.error(error.message || error);
    return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
  }
}
```

And finally **signup.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import { User } from "../../models/user";
import { SignupService } from "../../services/signup/signup.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']
})

export class SignupComponent {

  user: User = {
    id:0, 
    name:'Test',
    email:'test@test.com',
    birthDate: new Date()
    };

  constructor(private signupService: SignupService) { }

  addUser():void {
    this.signupService.createUser(this.user)
    .subscribe(u => this.user = u);
  }
}
```

The errors I'm getting are :

> ERROR in src/app/services/signup/signup.service.ts (27,12): The type
>   argument for type parameter 'T' cannot be inferred from the usage.
>   Consider specifying the type arguments explicitly.
>
> Type argument candidate 'Response' is not a valid type argument
>   because it is not a supertype of candidate 'Response'.
>
> Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
>   Type 'ResponseType' is not assignable to type 'ResponseType'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
>   Type '"basic"' is not assignable to type 'ResponseType'.
>
> ERROR in src/app/services/signup/signup.service.ts (34,17): Property
>   'data' does not exist on type 'Promise'.

I'm actually a beginner. I tried to put `createUser(user: User): Observable<User>` instead of `createUser(user: User): Observable<any>` but I still get the same errors.
And I don't have any "data" or Promise type in my code, I don't get it.
If anyone could help me I would really appreciate it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine. try replacing this code in your service and check are you getting response or not.

```
createUser(user: User){
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http.post(this.url, user, options).map((response: Response) => 
response.json());}
```